# How to use dropdownlist with a IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, unit-of-work

I have this code:

```
@{ 
     xx.Data.UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new xx.Data.UnitOfWork();
     var empresas= unitOfWork.EmpresaRepository.Get();
 }
 <div class="editor-field">
     @Html.DropDownList("Empresa", new SelectList(empresas))
 </div>
```

Variable empresas is an `IEnumerable<Empresa>`
Empresa has an ID and a Name

I need to show the name in the dropdownlist and of course the ID will be the key

The end result of what I did is this: http://screencast.com/t/MvdaPZ5P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [overload of the SelectList constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist.aspx) that takes a Value property name and Text property name:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Empresa", new SelectList(empresas, "ID", "Name"))
```